# Separate regular expression in mini regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have a regular expression to verify email and I want separate this in mini regular expression to check each

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/
```

each expression should be checked like this

```
const reg = [
        {
           'reg' : /\s/,
           'msg' : 'the mail cannot contain blank spaces'
        },



for (const key in reg) {
    if(reg[key].reg.test(mail)){
      (this as any).errorMessage = reg[key].msg
      return false
    }
  }
```

This allows you to get a different error message

How can I separate the  regular expression?

Comment: "*the mail cannot contain blank spaces*" - but it can! It's perfectly valid according to the email standard and also to the regular expression you found. (Btw, please share the source of that regex).

Comment: Do you understand how the regular expression you found works? Can you describe it in words? There is no single true decomposition of a regular expression into parts that can be checked individually, you need to find those parts (and the error messages you want to apply) on your own.

Comment: What's this: `(this as any)`?

Comment: @zer00ne (bad) TypeScript